# Create folders based on values in multiple xml files and copy content into them

Tags: xml, powershell

I am struggling and wondered if someone could help me...

I have many folders and each one will have a large xml file in it. I would to recurse through my folders and find my xml file. Once I have this xml I would like to pull some values from the xml and create a folder on a web server with a version subfolder and then copy a jpg file to it from the parent folder. So far I can get a single xml and return all the values of a field but cannot get it to create the folders based on the value. Would be nice if the script ignores if the folder exists. My xml would look something like this...

DATA

- ASSET

  - PART

    - Version "1"
    - partnumber "ABC123"
    - CAR

      - make "FORD"
      - colour "BLACK.JPG"
    - CAR

      - make "FERRARI"
      - colour "RED.JPG"

so the result should be folder structure like this

ABC123\

```
   1\
     FORD\
          black.jpg
     FERRARI\
           red.jpg
```

Apologies for the poor quality of the data in the post, first time posting and I couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Here's on possible approach:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<Data>
  <Asset>
    <Part version="1" partnumber="ABC123">
      <Car make="Ford" colour="Black.jpg"/>
      <Car make="Ferrari" colour="Red.jpg"/>
    </Part>
  </Asset>
</Data>
'@

$xmlPath = "C:\foo"
$pathRoot = "\\server\share\"
foreach ($part in $xml.Data.Asset.Part)
{
    $dir = $part.partnumber
    mkdir $pathRoot\$dir -WhatIf
    foreach ($car in $part.Car)
    {
        $dir = Join-Path $dir $car.make
        mkdir $pathRoot\$dir -WhatIf
        $colour = $car.colour
        Copy-Item $xmlPath\$dir\$colour $pathRoot\$dir\$colour -WhatIf
    }
}
```

$xmlPath would point to the directory containing the xml file.  I assume that is where you could be copying the jpg files from.

Comment: thanks Keith, can you explain why you put the @' with the xml content after it? I also wanted it to look recursively for xml files. This looks really good so far. Thanks for all the effort :)

Comment: That is called a `here string` and it used to create strings that span multiple lines.  Recursively finding xml files is easy using Get-ChildItem e.g. `Get-ChildItem <root-path> -recurse *.xml`.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, do I need to add this bit to my script  $xml = [xml]@'
<Data>
  <Asset>
    <Part version="1" partnumber="ABC123">
      <Car make="Ford" colour="Black.jpg"/>
      <Car make="Ferrari" colour="Red.jpg"/>
    </Part>
  </Asset>
</Data>
'@

Comment: No. That is just a sample of what I *think* the contents of your XML file look like.  You need to read in your actual XML file like so `$xml = [xml](Get-Content <path-to-xml-file>)`.